# Vertical fixed top navbar on Bootstrap 4 Beta

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar, vertical-scroll

I'm trying to build a vertical fixed top navbar with **Bootstrap 4 Beta**. I have found on the web several examples of Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6, but they do not work with Bootstrap 4 Beta. I have the problem that when the navbar assumes the fixed-top class the links and the the collapsed navbar move to the left. Below are links to html image with code:

[Html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhVng.jpg)

You can see the menu behavior and code at this address: 
http://www.fedelemarcopascuzzi.it/verticalnavbar/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Put the relevant code in the question itself. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the exact same problem!  The behavior looks a bit like it thinks the display is small and is rendering the menu as if it were on a phone.

Edit:
Alpha samples don't work, this code is working for me:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/